# External USB Drive not recognized after blue screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, bsod

While I was copying files from my PC's SSD/C: drive to an external USB hard drive, I suddenly got a blue screen (I'm having BSOD frequently caused by `ntoskrnl.exe`).

After restarting, a message box popped up saying that the previous drive couldn't be found (I can't remember the exact message).

I replugged the external drive and nothing happened, no drive showed up in the "This PC" section. Even after restart.

I plugged in a USB stick and it was recognized, but the drive was not at all.

**Edit:**
As far as I remember, the message box was like this:

[image: ]MessageBox]

**Edit 2:** 
The drive contains important data that I need to recover.

**Edit 3:**
The drive has been vibrating and the drive's LED is on since my attempt to copy data, although it should, as far as I know, stop and enter stand-by mode.

Comment: Does it hurt to leave a comment?

Comment: Probably the sudden interuption of the copy operation left the partition table corrupt. Had this happen the other day. Do you need to recover data from the drive? Or are you ok with reformatting the whole thing? (and loosing your data on the drive)

Comment: @Blaine I need to recover the data.

Comment: "Should I check whether the drive is recognized by another computer (Linux/Win10?) or try something different first?" Yes. This is the prerequisite for asking questions here. That's probably why you got a downvote.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question. Your edit 4 should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, my guess would be that the partition table was corrupted when the operation was unsuccessfully closed. Let's try to recover data first and then worry about making the drive usable again.

To check if the files are still in fact there, try scanning it with [File Scavenger](http://www.quetek.com/prod02.htm). The free version will let you see a gui with the filestructure, but not allow you to copy files. Assuming this works, you can then use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (a free tool that does basically the same thing) to copy the files over to another drive.

With recovery out of the way, we can go about re-formatting the drive. It doesn't show up in explorer because it is corrupt, but you should be able to view it in disk management (run the command `diskmgmt.msc`. Once you have done this, right click on the volume (I think) and select reformat the whole drive as FAT32.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried to recover deleted files (files I moved to the external HD before) from a partition of my SSD first, but unfortunately the bytes were (almost) all NULL (probably because I optimized that disk afterwards. That was a huge mistake). I found files on the external HD and I will try using TestDisk on a Linux computer.

Comment: Solved it. See my last edit. Thank you for your help anyway!!

Comment: @xoxox HAHAHA that is the strangest solution ever. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I simply pulled out the power cable from the drive, replugged it and everything was fine. The data was untouched.